# redis2_query & proxy_pass together

Tags: nginx, redis

I am trying to implement security to APIs via Nginx. Basically I will allow APIs only if a token exists in redis

```
location /api/ {
                if ($http_securitytoken = "") { return 403; }
                if ($http_securitytoken){
                             redis2_query get $http_securitytoken;
                             redis2_pass 127.0.0.1:6379;
                }

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9003;
        }
```

The issue here is what I want is redis2_query results to a variable, instead it is sending response and my proxy_pass is not working anymore, instead the redis result is getting send as output.

How to resolve?

Comment: The redis2 module doesn't do that, and authorization belongs in your web application, not in nginx.